# ListView in Fragment backstack still calling getView()

Tags: android, listview, fragment, fragment-backstack

I have a `Fragment` which contains a `ListView` say `FragmentA`, when I add another Fragment which contains another `ListView` say `FragmentB`:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, FragmentB)
    .commit()
```

I noticed that `getView()` of `ListView` in `FragmentA` is still getting called even though the top fragment is now `FragmentB`, any reason why and how do I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're stacking fragments on top of each other.

Instead of `add` use `replace` to replace any existing fragments in that container.

Comment: replace means I won't be able to go back to `FragmentA`, correct?

Comment: @SiGanteng No it doesnt't. As long as you add the transaction to the backstack.

Comment: Ok will give it a try then, thanks. I intuitively thought replace means taking out (delete) whatever fragment in that view and replace =/.